# How to display on root window in Java?

Tags: java, linux, swing, fullscreen, screensaver

I made a Windows screensaver with Java Swing and Launch4J, and I want to port it to Linux.  The obvious method is to use Xscreensaver to display the screensaver, as it just requires a single line added to a config.

My question is how to tell Java (either in code or as a command line argument to the JVM) to display a Swing app on the X server root window, as is required for Xscreensaver.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can. Java is meant to be platform-independent, so you typically can't do things that are specific to just one platform. But there may be a hidden command line option or something. Don't quote me on this, though.

Comment: If you can hunt down a copy of the SaverBeans core code, you might be able to get it sorted.  SaverBeans was the (short lived) Java based project that was compatible with Windows and *nix.  It used the XScreenSaver settings config. format and for *nix, used XScreenSaver itself to launch them.

Comment: @AndrewThompson SaverBeans is on GitHub, I'm checking it out now.